# Drag and drop functionality of Radscheduler control with MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, telerik-mvc, radscheduler

I have added telerik's rad-scheduler control for my MVC application.I have to apply the drag and drop functionality with the scheduler.I can see thet its already with the AJAX .How can i incorporate with my MVC application.I am new in MVC.Please provide a step by step solution.It will very helpful for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use OnClientAppointmentMoveStart funntion  on your javascript.

```
function OnClientAppointmenMoving(sender, eventArgs){
            //your code. 
        }
```

and refer it in your radcontrol in HTML.